# SQL, setting an indicator for duplicate record

Tags: sql, duplicates, indicator

I have a table which has a similar structure as below

```
+----------+----------------+---------+
| Session  |  StudentNumber |    Marks|
+-------------------------------------+
| 1        |  1234          |  90     |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1        |  1345          |  90     |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1        |  1456          |   90    |
+-------------------------------------+
```

I want to set an indicator called "PrintMarksInd" to N if all the values of the Marks column is same (as above).

If suppose the table is as below, then PrintMarksInd is to be set as Y

```
+--------+----------------+-----------+    
| Session|  StudentNumber |  Marks    |
+--------+----------------+-----------+
|   2    |    999         |  90       |
+--------+----------------+-----------+
|   2    |    980         |   90      |
+--------+----------------+-----------+
|   2    |    970         |  98       |
+--------+----------------+-----------+
|   2    |    960         |   98      |
+--------+----------------+-----------+    
|   2    |    950         |  60       |
+--------+----------------+-----------+
```

Please help me in setting the PrintMarksIndicator

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what's to say that 2 students couldnt score exactly the same marks?

Comment: Exactly, why would you consider them duplicates?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "an indicator" - what's do your expected *results* look like?

Comment: What you should be looking for is duplication of student numbers in a given session - ie in session 1 you couldnt have student 10 in twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like this:

```
DECLARE @indicator int
DECLARE @PrintMarksInd varchar(1)
select @indicator = count( distinct marks) from yourtable
if(@indicator = 1)
set @PrintMarksInd = 'Y'
else
set @PrintMarksInd = 'N'
```

i.e, if the count is 1 then all the records have same value else it has different values as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul. I have used count and wrapped that count inside decode statement. Now it will be set to N if count is 1 else it will be Y.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Session,
    student_number,
    marks,
    IF((SELECT 
        COUNT(marks)
        FROM
            Grades
        WHERE
            marks = table_one.marks) > 1,
    'Y',
    'N') AS PrintMarksInd
FROM
    Grades AS table_one
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Session,
    student_number,
    marks,
    IF((SELECT count(distinct marks)
        FROM
    Grades) = 1,
    'N',
    'Y') AS PrintMarksInd
FROM
    Grades
```

Comment: if I understand you correctly this is that what you want!

Answer (score 0):

create this function:

```
create FUNCTION message_box ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @message_text  VARCHAR(50);
If (select count(distinct marks)  from students_table) > 1
set @message_text = 'not all students have the same mark'
else 
set @message_text='all students have the same mark'
return @message_text    
END;
```

then use the message_box() function in a query:

```
select top 1 dbo.message_box() as PrintMarksIndicator
from students_table
```

you'll get only the message 'all students have the same mark' or 'not..'
if that is what you looking for :)

```
+----------+----------------+---------+
| Session  |  StudentNumber |    Marks|
+-------------------------------------+
| 1        |  1234          |  90     |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1        |  1345          |  90     |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1        |  1456          |   90    |
+-------------------------------------+
```

you'll get

```
+----------+----------------------------+
| PrintMarksIndicator                   |  
+---------------------------------------+
|wtf? all students have the same mark?       |  
+---------------------------------------+
```